# SuperCSV missing package in JAR

Tags: supercsv

This sounds silly but I can't find the package org.supercsv.mock in any JAR file i've downloaded for SuperCSV.

Does anyone know where this package is located?

Answer (score 1):

That package is purely used for test/example classes (which are not in any distributed jars that you can download).

You can view the source of the classes in this package by:

- checking them out of the Super CSV [subversion repository](http://sourceforge.net/p/supercsv/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/super-csv/src/test/java/org/supercsv/mock/), or
- viewing the [test source cross-reference](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/xref-test/index.html).